# Error Parsing JPQL on EclipseLink (Hermes Parser)

Tags: postgresql, eclipselink, jpql

I'm having a hard time trying to solve an issue using JPQL.
I'm working to fix some performance issues on a system and I don't have too much space to change the structure of the project (DB tables and/or Entities).

There is a problem of Select N+1 on the code because this system is doing an extensive use of Native Queries. So I decided to pick the worst queries and try to convert them to JPQL.

I'm not sure yet if this is the best solution for the scenario above.

Original Native Query:

```
SELECT is.*
FROM (SELECT id_map, id_spot, 
      json_array_elements(id_itineraries)::text::integer AS itinerary
      FROM itinerary_spot WHERE id_map=?) tmp
JOIN itinerary_spot is ON tmp.id_spot=is.id_spot AND tmp.id_map=is.id_map 
WHERE tmp.itinerary=?
```

This query is working OK, but it's not making the JOIN with entity Spot to avoid the *Select N+1*.

At this point I have thought about 2 different alternatives:

1. Improving the Native SQL Query adding the JOIN to Spot table and then using a @SqlResultSetMapping to fill up the Entities (Itinerary and Spot).
2. Converting the Query to a JPQL and let the EclipseLink 2.6 do its magic.

I don't feel confident enough to use the 1st solution because it would involve some messy code to iterate on the result and fill up the Entities.

So I decided to give a shot on the 2nd option. I converted the Native query to 
Full Query:

```
SELECT is FROM ItinerarySpot is, 
                (SELECT cs.itinerarySpotPK.idMap, 
                        cs.itinerarySpotPK.idSpot, 
                        SQL('json_array_elements(id_itineraries)::text::integer') AS itinerary 
                 FROM ItinerarySpot cs
                 WHERE cs.itinerarySpotPK.idMap = :idMap
                ) x
WHERE x.idSpot = is.itinerarySpotPK.idSpot
  AND x.idMap = is.itinerarySpotPK.idMap
  AND x.itinerary = :idItinerary

List<ItinerarySpot> fullJPQLResult = baseDAO.runQuery( ItinerarySpot.class, fullJPQL, params );
```

The problem is, I'm getting an error from EclipseLink (HermesParser) that is not helping me to identify what is wrong with my JPQL:

```
Exception Message:
An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: Exception Description: Internal problem encountered while compiling [<my-query-above>]. Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException

Exception Stacktrace: 
[org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1616), 
        org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1636), 
        com.mycompany.dao.BaseDAO.runQuery(BaseDAO.java:781), 
        com.mycompany.bo.impl.retail.ItinerarySpotBO.findItinerarySpots(ItinerarySpotBO.java:357), 
        com.mycompany.bo.impl.retail.ItineraryBO.buildItineraryFull(ItineraryBO.java:316), 
        com.mycompany.bo.impl.retail.ItineraryBO.buildItineraryStatus(ItineraryBO.java:366), 
        com.mycompany.bo.impl.retail.ItineraryBO.listItineraries(ItineraryBO.java:518), 
        com.mycompany.bo.impl.retail.SpotBO.buildSpotActivities(SpotBO.java:520), 
        com.mycompany.bo.impl.retail.SpotBO.buildSpotActivities(SpotBO.java:473), 
        com.mycompany.action.retail.ActivityAction.recommendedActivities(ActivityAction.java:149), 
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method), 
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57), 
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43), 
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606), 
        com.mycompany.service.ActionInvoker.invokeAction(ActionInvoker.java:128), 
        com.mycompany.service.JSONService.service(JSONService.java:101), 
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729), 
                ...
                ...
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)]
```

When I remove **'AND x.itinerary = :idItinerary'** from the Full JPQL does work (it does compile and execute).

Any help to identify the issue is welcome. I'm also opened to try another approach to solve the Select N+1.

Comment: You would need to show the full stack, where the NPE occurs in the parser, but any NPE is usually considered a bug.

Comment: This was the stack showed to me. There is nothing more from EclipseLink.
The part of stacktrace which I've suppressed is from Tomcat receiving the HTTP request.
Do you know if there is a way to increase the verbosite of EclipseLink other the Logging configuration, which I already put in ALL.

Comment: logging is shown here https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging . EclipseLink errors have the internal error included, so I don't know why it wouldn't be printed off - you'll have to check your application or container error handling code.

Comment: I didn't see any additional information on Tomcat's error handling. I mean, Tomcat have printed the same exception showed in my question. I did solve my issue removing the last clause in the WHERE and filtering it on Java level. I couldn't afford more time trying the JPQL-only solution. Maybe, when I have some time, I will go back at this point and tried it again.

Anyway, thanks for your help Chris.